# Specifying a type in an interface of the type that inherits this interface

Tags: c#, class, types, interface

Need a real implementation of this code

```
interface IExample{
   public this ReturnMe();
}
class Example : IExample {
   public this ReturnMe(){...} //returns an instance of the Example class
}
```

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xrncyy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return interface itself:

```cs
interface IExample
{
    public IExample ReturnMe();
}
class Example : IExample
{
    public IExample ReturnMe() => new Example();
}
```

Or use [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern):

```cs
interface IExample<T> where T : IExample<T>
{
    public T ReturnMe();
}

class Example : IExample<Example>
{
    public Example ReturnMe() => new Example();
}
```

Note that this will not prevent somebody from writing `class Example : IExample<SomeOtherClass>`.

Another option available since C# 9 is switching to abstract base class and using [covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns):

```cs
abstract class ExampleBase
{
    public abstract ExampleBase ReturnMe();
}
class Example : ExampleBase
{
    public override Example ReturnMe() => new Example();
}
```

Comment: Number 2 does not suit me since there is no general inheritance.  Option 1 suits me, but not completely, I would like the class itself to be returned (most likely in C # this is impossible)

Comment: Ed: You can specify "where T: IExample" in option 2 for inheritance, but option 1 will still work better

Comment: @NickName73 added another option - see the update.